# USN Journal : Has File been Updated

Tags: windows, delphi, computer-forensics

I have written a module in Delphi that enumerates all the files on a volume.
How do I get to know the files that were updated / deleted / created since my last backup ?
Noticed that the FileUSNReference number and the ParentFileUSNReference number change upon any update done to the file. If I have stored the file details during my previous backup and if I compare the numbers with the current Reference numbers I can get to know that the files have changed.
Just need to know if this is a reliable method as this is just my observation and I do not know if this is how it is supposed to be

Comment: The `FileUSNReference` and `ParentFileUSNReference` fields are just reference numbers that link the file to its parent folder, nothing more. Their values are arbitrary. The `Usn` field contains the actual **U**pdate **S**equence **N**umber of the file, and the `Reason` field contains the reason why the change was made. Read the MSDN documentation for more details: [Change Journals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363798.aspx).